# "The GLFW library is not initialized" after successful glfwInit()

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to rewrite an aplication to support GLFW3.  The problem I've run into is that `glfwInit()` will return true but then `glfwWindowHint` and `glfwCreateWindow` will repeatedly throw `GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED` before the program ends itself on `if (!window)`.

```
int main( void )
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```